# Hiding actions in Magnolia version is 5.7

Tags: magnolia

Is there a way to hide an existing action from the page browser (right click menu and in the sidebar) in Magnolia version is 5.7?

**Update:** I managed to accomplish the task by using the info.magnolia.module.delta.RemoveNodesTaskand and including this task in the ModuleVersionHandler. Is there a better way of doing it? Can I use `override!` for this?

These contents for the decorator file did not work:   pages.subApps.browser.actionbar.sections.pageActions.groups

```
versionActions: !override
   items:
     export: {}
     import: {}
```

or

```
versionActions: !override
     items:
```

or

```
versionActions: !override
  items:
    export:
        name: export
    import:
        name: import
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called the action bar in the Magnolia realm.

You can do two things:

- Delete permanently, by removing the node completely
- Disable it based on some availability rule. Either custom or an already implemented Java class.

Here is the documentation for it: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Action+bar+definition

Cheers,